# How do I suffix nginx logs with date

Tags: unix, nginx

Whats the best way to suffix nginx logs with date? I have the following in my nginx.conf. I need the logs saved as access.log.YYYY-MM-DD and error.log.YYYY-MM-DD instead.

```
##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the logrotate configuration file for Nginx - `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` to include `dateext` and `dateformat`.

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {

    <...>       

    dateext
    dateformat .%Y-%m-%d.log

    <...>

    prerotate
        <...>
        rm -f /var/log/nginx/access.`date +\\%Y-%m-d`.log
        rm -f /var/log/nginx/error.`date +\\%Y-%m-d`.log
        <...>
    endscript
    postrotate
        <...>
        ln -s /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/access.`date +\\%Y-%m-d`.log
        ln -s /var/log/nginx/error.log /var/log/nginx/error.`date +\\%Y-%m-d`.log
        <...>
    endscript

}
```

Example: access.2015-04-08.log

Read more on logrotate and its configuration directive by executing `man logrotate` in your linux.

Comment: However, lets say if i am rotating the logs daily, current day’s log will not have the suffix because I think the suffix will be added only when the log gets rotated. Is there a way for the current log to also have the suffix ?

Comment: Try to adding a pre & post rotate commands to symlink to the current date/log. See my * untested * example.